# Which are the the valid VHDL compiler pragmas?

Tags: vhdl, synthesizer

I know you can stop VHDL code from being compiled by the synthesizer:

```
-- pragma translate_off
assert thisDoesNotGetSynthesized();
-- pragma translate_on
```

BUT, there are also other ways to write this, including `-- synopsys translate_off`.

Which are all the valid ways to turn off synthesis? Is there a definitive list on which are valid pragmas?

Additionally: what are the *syntax rules* for these pragmas? Is the whitespace in the pragma important? Can the pragma occur anywhere in any comment, or does it need to be the only thing in that comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there does not seem to be a single list of all the pragma's accepted by all the different tools, I made an attempt to compose such a list myself.

http://www.sigasi.com/content/list-know-vhdl-metacomment-pragmas

Feel free to post comments if you find any omissions or inaccuracies.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~tweng/cse143/VHDLReference/11.pdf) for details on these:

```
–– pragma resolution_method wired_and
–– pragma resolution_method wired_or
-– pragma resolution_method three_state 

-– pragma map_to_entity entity_name
–– pragma return_port_name port_name
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge:

`-- synopsys translate_off`

`-- pragma translate_off`

`-- synthesis translate_off`

Depending on the synthesizer tool they might or might not work.

Comment: I'm sure there are a lot more though. I had hoped someone had already done the research put a list of valid pragmas together.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant ways to turn off synthesis only. My bad.